# problem_definition:I want to write a pl/SQL block to input marks of three subjects and want to display the result for the same (in percentage)

Tags: plsql

ORA-06550: line 11, column 20: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "<" when expecting one of the following: I got this error when i runned the block ..please help today is my exam.

```
declare
sub1 number;
sub2 number;
sub3 number;
percent real;
begin
sub1:=:Subject1;
sub2:=:Subject2;
sub3:=:Subject3;
percent:=(sub1+sub2+sub3)/3;
if (percent >=0 and <35)
then
dbms_output.put_line(F);
elsif (percent >=35 and <50)
then
dbms_output.put_line(d);
elsif (percent >=50 and <65)
then
dbms_output.put_line(c);
elsif (percent >=65 and <80)
then
dbms_output.put_line(b);
elsif  (percent >=80)
then
dbms_output.put_line(a);
endif;
end;
```

Comment: if (percent >=0 and percent <35)

Comment: thanks a lot honeyboy Wilson

Comment: I have added f (percent >=0 and percent <35) but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

"Percent" is missing almost *everywhere*. `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` requires a string as a parameter, so you should enclose all those letters into single quotes.

This, at least, compiles:

```
DECLARE
   sub1      NUMBER;
   sub2      NUMBER;
   sub3      NUMBER;
   percent   REAL;
BEGIN
   sub1 := :subject1;
   sub2 := :subject2;
   sub3 := :subject3;
   percent := (sub1 + sub2 + sub3) / 3;

   IF (    percent >= 0
       AND percent < 35)
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('F');
   ELSIF (    percent >= 35
          AND percent < 50)
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('d');
   ELSIF (    percent >= 50
          AND percent < 65)
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('c');
   ELSIF (    percent >= 65
          AND percent < 80)
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('b');
   ELSIF (percent >= 80)
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('a');
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many syntax errors in your code, check out the below code that I made the corrections and compare your code then you can understand where you are missing the keywords.

```
    declare
    sub1 number;
    sub2 number;
    sub3 number;
    percent number;
    begin
/*    sub1:= :Subject1;
    sub2:= :Subject2;
    sub3:= :Subject3;*/
    sub1:= 40;
    sub2:= 76;
    sub3:= 84;
    percent:= (sub1+sub2+sub3)/3;
    if (percent between 0 and 34) then
        dbms_output.put_line('F');
    elsif (percent between 35 and 49) then
        dbms_output.put_line('d');
    elsif (percent between 50 and 64) then
        dbms_output.put_line('c');
    elsif (percent between 65 and 79) then
        dbms_output.put_line('b');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('a');
    end if;
    end;
```